# My Laravel Db password contains a # and it is considered as a comment

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My Laravel Db password contains a # and it is considered as a comment. Can anyone provide me with a solution, The db password cannot be changed as it is hosted by some 3rd party vendor, i can login with the same creds on my mysql workbench.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=MYPassword#
```

Comment: Can you post the code handling the authentication?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97736 has some hints on possible escape characters / sequences you could try.

Comment: sure will let you know if i find a solution

Comment: Thank you for your comments i have found the solution on github and @CBroe your comment also helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solution on [github thread][1] and solution provided by CBroe, the answer is to wrap the string in ""

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD="MYPassword#"


  [1]: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27850
```